# HTML Element with Display:none defaulting width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slickgrid

In my CSS, I have set a div to display:none, for when the page originally loads, and width set to 100%. However, on the page load, I also have a slickgrid getting generated, using that container.  When I then set the div to display:block via jquery, I see that the slickgrid is not a width of 100%, but defaulting to 100px - when stepping through the slick grid code, I am seeing the following code returning 100, for my container which is set to display:none

```
$.css($container[0], "width", true)
```

Is there any way to get around what seems to be a default width for an element with display:none? I have tried setting the width in the same CSS block, with no luck.

```
 .data-grid{
        height: 350px;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
}
```

TIA

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? any why width true? normally there is no default width and I don't know where you got that width = true from

Comment: This is odd, I have a site that uses display: none; width: 100%; and it works perfect. Are you sure you dont have any conflicting CSS or any misspellings? I know it sounds basic but those are things I find myself missing.

Comment: `display:none` should not affect the `width`. You have something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't create a jsFiddle, as I have restricted access at work.  To clarify, after I set 'display:block', the width _is_ at 100% - it's only _before_ then that accessing the width returns 100, instead of 100%.

Comment: When I remove the `display:none` from the CSS completely, my slickgrid is displaying correctly (with the width I expect), which is what leads me to believe that it's the `display:none` that's causing the issue

Comment: can you at least provide a little more code? and you haven't explained yet what you expect css width true to do.. as already stated it has nothing to do with display none. are there any javascript errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - apparently you cannot use percentage with display:none - changed it to a fixed pixel width, and it's working now

Answer (score -1):

You could try $("elementInQuestion").css("width", "100%"); I think your "%" is getting lopped off somewhere.